# how can i export a reducer object in redux

Tags: redux, next.js

am new to redux, i created a addToBasket and removeBasket object in my reducers variable but when am trying to export it so i can use it in another component, am getting an Error
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'addToBasket' of 'basketSlice.action' as it is undefined. i don't know if am not destructuring it the right way, please can someone help out, i don't know what am doing wrong

here is my code

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
    items: [],
}

export const basketSlice = createSlice({
    name: "basket",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        addToBasket: (state, action) => {
            state.items = [...state.items, action.payload]
        },
        removeFromBasket: (state, action) => {},
    }
});

export const { addToBasket, removeFromBasket} = basketSlice.action;

export default basketSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo there - it's `actions`, not `action`.

```
export const { addToBasket, removeFromBasket} = basketSlice.actions;
```